# Session Variable in Select Where Statement

Tags: php, mysql

I tried the code below but it didn't work.

```
$this->datatables->select('id_payment,nama_donatur,tgl_pembayaran,nama_jenis_pmb,nominal');
$this->datatables->from('tbl_pembayaran');
$this->datatables->where('nama_donatur = $_SESSION["full_name"]');
```

I know for sure it has to do with the SELECT statement using the variable, im not sure if I am relating to the variable correctly.

Comment: Any error you are getting?

Comment: What framework is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables are not expanded in single quoted string literals, so try this instead

```
$this->datatables->where('nama_donatur = ' . $_SESSION["full_name"]);
```

Or you may need to do this as that is probably a string column

```
$this->datatables->where("nama_donatur = '$_SESSION[full_name]'");
```

> And of course make sure that you have started the session using `session_start()`

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is vulnerable to SQL injection, but I don't know which framework this is.